# Sort vs SortWithLimit in snowflake query profile

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

what is the difference between the execution of sort and sortwithlimit?
How order by works with limit?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of ORDER BY and LIMIT is implemented as a special operator, shown as "SortWithLimit" in the query profile.

This operator does not spill to disk when processing more than a certain amount of data and therefore can run out of memory.

Details: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Out-of-memory-error-caused-by-LIMIT-and-or-OFFSET-clause